# MongoDB: Aggregating multidimensional info into a panel data

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo, aggregation

I am a beginner in MongoDB and I am learning aggregations. I have the following document which is information from Inflation, it looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60678f561091100d5dbe2ddf"
    },
    
    "V": 0.21,
    "D1C": "202001",    
    "D2C": 63,    
    "D3C": 7169,
    
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60678f561091100d5dbe2de0"
    },    
    "V": 0.39,
    "D1C": "202001",    
    "D2C": 63,    
    "D3C": 7170,
    
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60678f561091100d5dbe2de1"
    },    
    "V": 0.2,
    "D1C": "202001",    
    "D2C": 63,    
    "D3C": 7171,
    
},

(...)

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60678f561091100d5dbe2fa8"
    },    
    "V": 0.21,
    "D1C": "202001", 
    "D2C": 69,    
    "D3C": 7169,
    
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60678f561091100d5dbe2fa9"
    }
    "V": 0.39,
    "D1C": "202001",
    "D2C": 69,
    "D3C": 7170,
}
```

"V" is the value of the inflation, "D1C" is the month, "D2C" is the type of index (i.e. % yearly accumulated or % monthly) and "D3C" is the group of inflation (i.e. Food, Industry, Services).

I wanted to aggregate this data in such a way that would be easy to chose an arbitrary value of "D2C" and import the data into a pandas dataframe.

More specifically i wish i had the data in a way I could ask only for D2C=63 and get something like this:

```
[ { "7169" : {'01/2020' : 0.21, '02/2020' : 0.66, ...},
  { "5555" : {'01/2020' : 0.21, '02/2020' : 0.66, ...},]
```

In a way that i get all the groups as keys of a dict and the value would be a dict with pairs of the date and values referring to the group.

Thank you everyone, and happy easter!

Comment: Hi can you post some more `Inflation` data plz. Just need to know how did you get multiple `D1C`/`month` under `D3C`.

Comment: Sure!

The data I am specifically getting is from this API: http://api.sidra.ibge.gov.br/values/t/7060/p/all/v/all/C315/all/n1/1/f/a

There is some keys I remove because of the redundancy.

Basically it's a list of dicts where I have a set of all months for each D1C, D3C and D2C.

Comment: Hi can there be multiple entries for `D3C` for same `D2C`? For example two documents with `D3C` = 7170 for `D2C` = 63.

Comment: Yes, that's possible but only with different entries of time in `D1C`.

Comment: Ok then the below code will work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION #1**: If you want the output in single document.

1. Filter out documents with `D2C` = `63` using `$match` stage.
2. `$group` the results by month/`D3C` to get an array of format `{ k: "", v: ""}`.
3. `$group` it again by `null` to get an array of format `{ k: "", v: ""}`.
4. Convert array to object using [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/).

Try this:

```js
db.Inflation.aggregate([
    { 
        $match: { "D2C": 63 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$D3C",
            array: { 
                $push: { k: "$D1C", v: "$V" }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            array: {
                $push: {
                    k: { $toString: "$_id" },
                    v: { $arrayToObject: "$array" }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$array" }
        }
    }
])
```

Output for SOLUTION #1:

```js
{
    "7169" : {
        "202001" : 0.21
    },
    "7170" : {
        "202001" : 0.39
    },
    "7171" : {
        "202001" : 0.2
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION #2**: If you want the output as an array of documents.

```js
db.Inflation.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { "D2C": 63 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$D3C",
            array: {
                $push: { k: "$D1C", v: "$V" }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $arrayToObject: [
                    [{
                        k: { $toString: "$_id" },
                        v: { $arrayToObject: "$array" }
                    }]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Output for SOLUTION #2:

```js
[
  {
    "7169": { "202001": 0.21 }
  },
  {
    "7170": { "202001": 0.39 }
  },
  {
    "7171": { "202001": 0.2 }
  }
]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed!! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Observe its an object inside an object not array of Objects as you have mentioned in expected output.